# Make property unreactive

Tags: lightning-web-components, scrolling

Let's say we have

```
renderedCallback() {
    if(!this.isRenedered) {
        console.log('is js scroll:',this.isJSScroll);
        const tempo = [...this.historyList];
        const targetDiv = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="MA0000029"]');
        const selector = `[data-id="${tempo[tempo.length - 2]?.trackingId}"]`;
        const targetDiv_ = this.template.querySelector(selector);
        this.isJSScroll = true;
        targetDiv?.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'instant', 
            block: 'start', 
            inline: 'nearest'});
        this.isJSScroll = false;
    }
    this.isRendered = true;

}
handleScroll = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    if(!this.isJSScroll && target.scrollHeight - target.scrollTop <= target.clientHeight) {
        console.log('handle scroll');
        this.loadMore();
        this.isRendered = false;
    }
}
```

when i try to use `targetDiv?.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'instant',  block: 'start',  inline: 'nearest'});`
it works fine cause we are retrieving a constant html element
but when it comes to targetDiv_ it performs an infinite loop and soner or later throws an error.
Is it possible to avoid that behavior?

Comment: is it a typo on variable name in actual code or just in this example: `if(!this.isRenedered) {`

Answer (score 4):

DOM updates don't immediately take effect, but instead are done the next time the browser takes control from JS. In other words, you're causing your own infinite loop. You should be able to fix this by adding a small delay to your code in the form of a `await Promise.resolve`.

```
async renderedCallback() {
    if(!this.isRendered) {
        console.log('is js scroll:',this.isJSScroll);
        const tempo = [...this.historyList];
        const targetDiv = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="MA0000029"]');
        const selector = `[data-id="${tempo[tempo.length - 2]?.trackingId}"]`;
        const targetDiv_ = this.template.querySelector(selector);
        this.isJSScroll = true;
        targetDiv?.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'instant', 
            block: 'start', 
            inline: 'nearest'});
        // Flush DOM updates
        await Promise.resolve();
        // Reset flag
        this.isJSScroll = false;
    }
    this.isRendered = true;
}
```

Alternatively, don't reset the flag in renderedCallback, but rather in the scroll handler.

```
handleScroll = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    if(!this.isJSScroll && target.scrollHeight - target.scrollTop <= target.clientHeight) {
        console.log('handle scroll');
        this.loadMore();
        this.isRendered = false;
    }
    this.isJSScroll = false;
}
```